# Reference question: $C^1$ estimate for a stable minimal surface

Tags: geometric-analysis, minimal-surfaces

I am looking for an answer/reference to the following question: Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold and $\Sigma\subset M$ a closed, stable minimal surface. Is it possible to prove $C^1$ estimates for $\Sigma$ that only depend on $C^0$-data of the metric tensor? Does the situation change if one replaces stability by area-minimizing?

I'm able to find several resources dealing with higher order (curvature) estimates which usually have a stronger dependence on $g$ (at least $C^1$) however.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a $C^{1}$ estimate for $\Sigma?$

Comment: Let's assume we can cover $M$ by finitely many charts. Then I would like that we can choose local parametrizations such that the $C^1$-norm of these parametrizations w.r.t. to these charts is uniformly bounded.